# How to use Travis CI with some files in gitignore?

Tags: python, flask, travis-ci, gitignore

I have a Flask app that has its configurations in a file called settings.py. I've put this file in .gitignore because the project is in a public repo. Travis-CI was working before I added tests into my project even though settings.py was in .gitignore. After adding tests to the project, the build started failing with the following output:

```
Debugged import:

- 'settings' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"

# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# command to run tests
script: python tests.py
```

Does this mean that in order to use travis-ci, we have to include all necessary files in the repo? Or is there a workaround? The repo on GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/mikaelm1/blind-chat-api).

Comment: This is very much application specific. If you require a settings module to run your application, then yes, a settings module needs to be available to Travis. There are a few approaches you can take. I like to have a `settings.py` that provides default values with a way to override them from something like environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dirn's comment of using a default `settings.py` file and then overriding some settings with [encrypted environment variables on Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) is a good idea, certainly worth it if there are only a couple of differences.

However, if you can't be bothered or it's too complicated breaking up your settings, you could install the Ruby [Travis command line client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) `gem`, which is useful for quite a few things.

With the client on your machine you can use [Travis' file encryption feature](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/) to encrypt your whole `settings.py` file, and then commit *the encrypted version* (which will have an `.enc` file extension) to GitHub. Travis will then be able to decrypt the file during the CI run, as long as you add the right commands to the `.travis.yml` file, say in a `before_install` step. Detailed instructions are on the file encryption page.

Comment: Thank you! I encrypted the whole file and by using the `--add` flag in the encryption, it even updated the .travis.yml file automatically for me.

Answer (score 2):

I did a trick in .travis.yml
After commit and before Travis build, create the ignored file like this:

```
before_install:
- cp .ignored.file.copy ignored.file
```

This way, the build will succeed without the actual gitignore-ed file.